# Using class from another file in python package and conflicts in __init__()

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, package

I'm writing a python package (python 3.6) and have the following directory structure:

```
package/
|  __init__.py
|  fileA.py
|  fileB.py
|  tests/
|  |  __init__.py
|  |  test_classA.py
|  |  test_classB.py
```

### Setup

My files have the following contents:

```
# package/fileA.py
from package import ClassB

def ClassA:
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_ClassB = ClassB()
```

-

```
# package/fileB.py
def ClassB:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = "bar"
```

-

```
# package/tests/test_classB.py
from package import ClassB

# <performs some unit tests here>
```

-

```
# package/tests/test_classA.py
from package import ClassA

# <performs some unit tests here>
```

-

```
# package/__init__.py
from .fileA import ClassA
from .fileB import ClassB
```

### Circular importing

When I ran `python test_classB.py`, I get the following traceback error showing that I have circular import statements, which are not allowed by python. Note - the package is not literally called `package` and I have edited the Traceback to match the toy example above.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "package/tests/test_classB.py", line 2, in <module>
    from package import ClassB
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/package/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .fileA import ClassA
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/package/merparse.py", line 2, in <module>
    from package import ClassB
ImportError: cannot import name 'ClassB'
```

### Correcting the error

However, when I remove those two lines in my `package/__init__.py` file:

```
# package/__init__.py
from .fileA import ClassA
from .fileB import ClassB
```

...and I change the import method for `package/fileA.py`:

```
# package/fileA.py
from package.fileB import ClassB

def ClassA:
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_ClassB = ClassB()
```

... `package/tests/test_classB.py` runs correctly.

### My Question

My question is: How can I keep the one file: one class structure in my files and import with `from package import ClassA` instead of having to import with `from package.fileA import ClassA`?

In my package I would like to import classes from other files, but don't know how to get around circular importing.

### Edit: Solution

Thanks to @mirandak and @martin-kalcok below for their help.

The only file that I had to edit was `fileA.py` to not refer to the package name in the import statement.

```
# package/fileA.py
from .fileB import ClassB

def ClassA:
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_ClassB = ClassB()
```

The `package/__init__.py` file still contains import statements in case I want to import the package from other scripts in the future that I don't couple with the package.

```
# package/__init__.py
from .fileA import ClassA
from .fileB import ClassB
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with `package/fileA.py`. It's both a part of `package` and calling the `__init__.py` file of `package` as it's imported - creating a circular dependency.

Can you change `fileA.py` to look like this?

```
# package/fileA.py
from .fileB import ClassB

def ClassA:
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_ClassB = ClassB()
```

Comment: Thank you - this fixed my problem. As a note for anyone else who might find this question, I edited my answer above to show how my files looked in the end. I was able to keep the import statements in my `package/__init__.py` file in case I want to interface with these classes outside of development for this package in the future.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, renaming your package to literary "package" really confuses this whole situation, but here's my take on it :D.
I don't think you are dealing with circular dependency, python just states that it cannot import `classB` from `package` and that is because there is no file named `classB` in `package` directory. Changing import statement to

```
from package.fileB import ClassB
```

works because there is directory `package` which contains file `fileB` which contains object `ClassB`.
To answer your question whether you can import classes with statement

```py
from package import ClassB
```

you can't, unless your `package` is file and `classB` is object inside this file. However i don't see how this different import statement would be a dealbraker
**Side Note**: Your objects `ClassB` and `ClassA` are not classes, they are functions. Python uses keyword `class` to create classes and `def` to define functions.
**Side note 2**: Are you sure your `__init__.py` file needs to hold any code at all?
**Personal Note**: I know that keeping 1 File / 1 Class structure is matter of personal preferences, it is not required in python and I myself find it much more comfortable to group multiple related classes and functions into one file

Comment: The `classB` in `package` comes from the `from .fileB import ClassB` line in `package/__init__.py`. Most modules would be able to do `from package import ClassB` just fine, but trying it from within a submodule of `package` creates a circular import.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have some comments about your side notes: **1.** Are you able to link me to something that explains in-detail the bit about objects being classes, instead of classes? I'm not entirely sure about how that is implemented in Python. **2.** The only reason I wanted to have the import statements in my `__init__.py` file was to allow my to use those classes in non-package scripts in the future. What do you think about this? **Personal note** I was hoping to keep them in separate files mostly because I'm a klutz and often break things when editing. Easier for `git` this way?

Comment: Hi, my answer was incorrect, as @user2357112 pointed out. I missed it because i don't usually use `__init__.py` file this way. I'll be editing my answer. Regarding the notes: __1.__ Here's pretty in-depth explanation https://www.quora.com/Why-are-functions-considered-first-class-objects-in-Python . __2.__ That is one way to achieve that. However, it is not required, you could use the longer version of import ( `from package.fileB import classB` ) outside of your "package" and it would work just fine. __Personal Note__ - Again, its just about preferences and I'm running out of comment space :D